# Generics and Pointers

Tags: pointers, delphi, generics

I have this code to demonstrate the question:

```
type
  PData = ^TData;
  TData = record
    ...
  end;

TBaseList<T> = class
  FList: TList<T>;
  ...
end;

TDataList = class(TBaseList<TData>);
type
  TProcTData = reference to procedure(var AData: TData); 
  TProcPData = reference to procedure(AData: PData);
public
  procedure TestT(AIndex: Integer; AProcT: TProcTData);
  procedure TestP(AIndex: Integer; AProcP: TProcPData);
end;

// This works, but we have 2 memory copying here (to Data and from Data)
procedure TDataList.TestT(AIndex: Integer; AProcT: TProcTData);
var
  Data: TData;
begin
  Data := FList[Index];
  AProcT(Data);
  FList[Index] := Data;
end;

procedure TDataList.TestP(AIndex: Integer; AProcP: TProcPData);
var
  Data: PData;
begin
  // Does not work
  AProcP(@FList[Index]);
  // Does not work too
  Data := @FList[Index];
  AProcP(Data);
end;
```

Here the question: I can use TestT method, but can't use TestP method.

Is it possible to do this with PData to reduce data copying to the local variable and from local variable?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes, actually the question is not about generics, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@FList[Index]` is never going to be of any use to you. This returns the address of the temporary local variable use to host the return value from the property getter. In fact I think that in modern versions of Delphi this won't compile.

You need to access the underlying array. Either

```
@FList.List[Index]
```

if you want the address of an item, or just

```
FList.List[Index]
```

if you are passing to a var parameter.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: In some cases, a more natural approach might be to use a reference type instead of a value type for the data (that is, let `TData` be a class instead of a record). But it all depends on the context.

Comment: Certainly, it all depends on the context (which isn't given in the Q).

Comment: Actually TData record contain print job detail, TBaseList<T> class is a threas safe list, TDataList.TestT - thread safe access to the print job info. I'm not sure that this is the best method to store such data